# How to obtain a specific table with a missing cell

Tags: tables

How should I proceed to obtain the  following table:

[image: table]

What I've tried is:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
 7 & 4 & 7 & 9 & 27\\ \hline
 10 & 9 & 9 & 6 & 34\\ \hline
 17 & 13 &  16 & 15 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{ } \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

but it does not work anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `\cline{1-4}` instead of `\hline` in the last line -- it will prevent the full line and print a line only for the first 4 cells, what's requested, most likely

Comment: As @ChristianHupfer says.  See also [Remove border of top left table cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64827)

Comment: also, you should probably have a look at [booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), which gives you a lot more professional looking tables, with some very good advice, in my, and many others opinion.