# \cline does not show on cell with background

Tags: tables, rules, backgrounds

I want to create a tabular with an empty top left cell and a background color on the column and row headers (except the empty top left).

I try to combine this two answers:
[color only a cell of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50349/color-only-a-cell-of-a-table)
[Remove border of top left table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64825/remove-border-of-top-left-table-cell)

But the background color seams to be drawn on top of the upper rule when using `\cline`. This does not happen with `\hline`.

How do I draw `\cline` on top of the background color?

```
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (rev 5238)
```

MCVE:

```
\documentclass[24pt a6paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[paperheight=3.7in,paperwidth=6.2in, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\sometext}{this is just to demonstrate line breaking}   
\definecolor{headercolor}{RGB}{209,220,204}

\newcommand{\cellDefinition}[1]{\parbox{3cm}{\vspace{3mm}#1\vspace{3mm}}}

This table has a line at the top of the gray cell (1-3) because of \verb|\hrule| :

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &    \cellDefinition{\sometext} & \cellcolor{headercolor}    \cellDefinition{\sometext} &    \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\ \hline
    \cellDefinition{\sometext} &    \cellDefinition{\sometext}  &   \cellDefinition{\sometext}  &   \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
\vspace{1em}

How do I draw the same (evenly thick) line on top of the gray cell with \verb|\crule| ?

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}\cline{2-4}\cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellDefinition{\sometext} & \cellcolor{headercolor}    \cellDefinition{how do I bring the line at top before the background? } &   \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\\hline
    \cellDefinition{\sometext}  & \cellcolor{headercolor}       \cellDefinition{I want such top line at the other cell too.} &  \cellDefinition{\sometext} &    \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 


\end{document}
```

result

[image]

Comment: this is explicitly documented in the `colortbl` documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to `\usepackage{hhline}` and have to replace `\cline{2-4}` by `\hhline{~|-|-|-|}`. The argument of `\hhline` is a specification of what to draw: `~` corresponds to an empty column, `-` to a line spanning one column, and `|` signals a junction with a vertical line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[24pt a6paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[paperheight=3.7in,paperwidth=6.2in, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\sometext}{this is just to demonstrate line breaking}   
\definecolor{headercolor}{RGB}{209,220,204}

\newcommand{\cellDefinition}[1]{\parbox{3cm}{\vspace{3mm}#1\vspace{3mm}}}

This table has a line at the top of the gray cell (1-3) because of \verb|\hrule| :

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &    \cellDefinition{\sometext} & \cellcolor{headercolor}    \cellDefinition{\sometext} &    \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\ \hline
    \cellDefinition{\sometext} &    \cellDefinition{\sometext}  &   \cellDefinition{\sometext}  &   \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
\vspace{1em}

How do I draw the same (evenly thick) line on top of the gray cell with \verb|\crule| ?

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}
    \hhline{~|-|-|-|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellDefinition{\sometext} & \cellcolor{headercolor}    \cellDefinition{how do I bring the line at top before the background? } &   \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\\hline
    \cellDefinition{\sometext}  & \cellcolor{headercolor}       \cellDefinition{I want such top line at the other cell too.} &  \cellDefinition{\sometext} &    \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For historical reasons, the command `\cline` draws a rule which protrude in the cell which is below (and `\hline` does not). In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, that behaviour is corrected.

So, by using `{NiceTabular}` instead of `{tabular}`, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass[24pt a6paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[paperheight=3.7in,paperwidth=6.2in, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\sometext}{this is just to demonstrate line breaking}   
\definecolor{headercolor}{RGB}{209,220,204}

\newcommand{\cellDefinition}[1]{\parbox{3cm}{\vspace{3mm}#1\vspace{3mm}}}

How do I draw the same (evenly thick) line on top of the gray cell with \verb|\crule| ?

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellDefinition{\sometext} & \cellcolor{headercolor}    \cellDefinition{how do I bring the line at top before the background? } &   \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\\hline
    \cellDefinition{\sometext}  & \cellcolor{headercolor}       \cellDefinition{I want such top line at the other cell too.} &  \cellDefinition{\sometext} &    \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

However, although mathematically perfect, the PDF produced by using the tools of `colortbl` is sometimes difficult to render by the PDF viewers: at some levels of zoom, some rules seems to vanish (even in Adobe Reader).

That's why `nicematrix` provides tools to solve those problems. With the key `colortbl-like` (and without loading `colortbl`), the PDF will be perfect in all PDF viewers at all levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass[24pt a6paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperheight=3.7in,paperwidth=6.2in, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\sometext}{this is just to demonstrate line breaking}   
\definecolor{headercolor}{RGB}{209,220,204}

\newcommand{\cellDefinition}[1]{\parbox{3cm}{\vspace{3mm}#1\vspace{3mm}}}

How do I draw the same (evenly thick) line on top of the gray cell with \verb|\crule| ?

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c|}[colortbl-like]
\cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellDefinition{\sometext} & \cellcolor{headercolor}    \cellDefinition{how do I bring the line at top before the background? } &   \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\\hline
    \cellDefinition{\sometext}  & \cellcolor{headercolor}       \cellDefinition{I want such top line at the other cell too.} &  \cellDefinition{\sometext} &    \cellDefinition{\sometext} \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]